# Concatenate all JSON key-value pairs into a String

Tags: java, json, concatenation

I have input:
{
"Id": 200,
"TimeStamp": 1596466800,
"Animal": "cat"
}

I need to concatenate all key-value pairs in one String

I need output:
"Id200Timestamp1596466800Animalcat"

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use a third-party library for parsing JSON. There are several. The below code uses [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Note that the below code is not terribly robust, it assumes that there are no nested elements and that the values are all primitives. That is what you specifically asked for, i.e. specific input and specific output, and I am posting a solution that achieves what you specifically asked for.

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class GsonTst0 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{ \"Id\": 200, \"TimeStamp\": 1596466800, \"Animal\": \"cat\"}";
        JsonElement root = JsonParser.parseString(json);
        if (root.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObj = root.getAsJsonObject();
            Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = jsonObj.entrySet();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
                sb.append(entry.getKey());
                JsonElement elem = entry.getValue();
                JsonPrimitive prim = elem.getAsJsonPrimitive();
                if (prim.isNumber()) {
                    sb.append(prim.getAsBigDecimal());
                }
                else {
                    sb.append(prim.getAsString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
Id200TimeStamp1596466800Animalcat
```